# How to create a Ramdisk and use it with Lightread?

Tags: ram, disk, lightread

I have created a Ramdisk for Chrome following these instructions:

```
1) Most of our commands require superuser privileges, so we might as well just switch to root.

sudo su -

2) Edit your startup script:

nano /etc/rc.local

Right above “exit 0″ we’ll add the commands that need to run each time at startup:

mkdir /tmp/ram

mount -t tmpfs -o size=512M,mode=750 tmpfs /tmp/ram/

chown -R yourUserName /tmp/ram/ (replace “yourUserName” with your user name)

Save the changes and exit (ctrl-o, ctrl-x).

3) Edit your boot configuration:

nano /etc/default/grub

Change the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line to read:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”ramdisk=512000″

and again save and exit.

4) Reboot and verify that /tmp/ram now exists with “drwxr-x—” rights with you as the owner.

5) Relocate your existing browser (no need to do this as root) cache and link to it:

For Chromium:

rm -rf  ~/.cache/chromium

ln -s /tmp/ram ~/.cache/chromium

For Google Chrome:

rm -rf  ~/.cache/google-chrome/

ln -s /tmp/ram ~/.cache/google-chrome

For Mozilla Firefox:

The cache for Firefox can be found inside your Firefox profile (which includes a big random string in it). As long as you only have one Firefox profile you can do this:

cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/*default

rm -rf Cache

ln -s /tmp/ram Cache
```

From here [Perfect Ubuntu: Optimizing Your Browser with a RAM Disk](http://www.kevingunn.org/?p=210)

I'd like to use Lightread with a Ramdisk, what should I do to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "light read"?  If the disk is in RAM, it won't matter what kind of read/write activity you have; you literally won't get faster storage except by buying faster RAM.

Comment: @gh403 light read is a rss client

Answer (score 0):

You can install Profile Sync Daemon. There is a tutorial: [Click here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/keep-your-browser-profiles-in-tmpfs-ram.html)

Comment: This works for the purpose of the putting the profile and the cache (depending on the browser) on RAM but it's clearly aimed at web browsers. What (if possible) should the OP do to use it with Lightread?.